# Profession "moutchoutier"?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, professions

En lisant un acte de naissance de 1937, je trouve derrière le nom du père sa profession, mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre le mot:

[image]

Le texte suit la date de naissance du père (mille huit cent `quatre vingt dix-neuf`, la profession que je n'arrive pas à lire/comprendre `o(?)moutchoutier` puis `, et de` (...)

Quelle peut être cette profession?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est très probablement [*caoutchoutier*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caoutchoutier) c'est-à-dire l' « ouvrier travaillant le caoutchouc; industriel traitant le caoutchouc » (TLFi) i.e. [(natural) [rubber](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caoutchouc)].

Comment: Je dois dire merci à Google ici, quand j'ai saisi « omoutchoutier » dans le moteur, il a présenté des résultats pour _caoutchoutier_ et c'est là que j'ai compris qu'il s'agissait d'un _a_ et non d'un _m_.

Comment: Ah - j'avais essayé la même chose (aussi avec "profession" devant) mais il n'a rien sorti du tout. En tout cas merci pour la réponse!